# Multiple REST API $expand not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, jquery

I am using SharePoint 2013 REST API. I have multiple fields that I would like to $expand.  It works when I put the following endpoint in the address bar

```
_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Project')/items?$select=ChiefEngineerInfo/EMail,AssistantChief/EMail&$expand=AssistantChief/Id&$expand=ChiefEngineerInfo/Id&$filter=Project_x0020_Number eq '402-I-001'
```

It does not work in my code.

```
        var endPointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Project')/items?$select=ChiefEngineerInfo/EMail,AssistantChief/EMail&$expand=AssistantChief/Id&$expand=ChiefEngineerInfo/Id$filter=Project_x0020_Number eq '"+projNum+"'";

    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: endPointUrl, 
        type: "GET", 
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }, 
        success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
            detailComplete(data); // Returns JSON collection of the results
        }, 
        error: function (err) { 
            console.log("Error Occured:" + JSON.stringify(err)); 
        }    
    });
```

I get the following error:

> Error
>   Occured:{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"The
>   expression
>   \\"AssistantChief/Id,ChiefEngineerInfo/Id$filter=Project_x0020_Number
>   eq '402-CSI-001'\\" is not
>   valid.\"}}}","responseJSON":{"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The
>   expression
>   \"AssistantChief/Id,ChiefEngineerInfo/Id$filter=Project_x0020_Number
>   eq '402-I-001'\" is not valid."}}},"status":400,"statusText":"Bad
>   Request"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have multiple $expand keyword, separate it out using comma.

```
$expand=AssistantChief/Id,ChiefEngineerInfo/Id
```